# call SQL function within R function

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, sqldf, nested-function

I am wondering if it is possible to call an `SQL` function within an `R` function?

Say for example that I have this dummy data and `SQL` function written in `Postgres 9.3`

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   id VARCHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY
   ,name TEXT
   ,year_born NUMERIC
   ,nationality TEXT
);

INSERT INTO tbl(id, name, year_born, nationality)
VALUES ('A1','Bill',2001,'American')
      ,('B1','Anna',1997,'Swedish')
      ,('A2','Bill',1991,'American')
      ,('B2','Anna',2004,'Swedish')
      ,('B3','Anna',1989,'Swedish')
      ,('A3','Bill',1995,'American');


CREATE FUNCTION retrieve_data(TEXT) 
RETURNS TABLE ( id VARCHAR(2), name TEXT, year_born NUMERIC, nationality TEXT ) AS 
$func$
SELECT id, name, year_born, nationality
FROM tbl
WHERE name=$1 OR nationality=$1
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
$func$ LANGUAGE sql
```

I can access this data and run the function within the `R` environment through the `RPostgreSQL` and `sqldf` packages as below;

```
require(RPostgreSQL)
require(sqldf)

options(sqldf.RPostgreSQL.user = "****", 
        sqldf.RPostgreSQL.password = "****",
        sqldf.RPostgreSQL.dbname = "test_db",
        sqldf.RPostgreSQL.host = "localhost", 
        sqldf.RPostgreSQL.port = 5432)

sqldf("select * from retrieve_data('Bill')")
```

But is there a way to call the above `SQL` function within an `R` function, e.g. like;

```
myfunc <- function(name) {
sqldf("select * from retrieve_data(name)")
}

myfunc('Bill')
```

Any pointers would be very much appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**

Using the `$fn` prefix in the `sqldf` package as suggested by @G. Grothendieck

```
myfunc2 <- function(name){
   fn$sqldf("select * from retrieve_data('$name')")
}
```

Or exchange the above `options` to the below code to match the suggested answer by @dickoa

```
require(RPostgreSQL)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv,
                 user="****",
                 password="****",
                 dbname="test_db",
                 host="localhost",
                 port=5432)
```

Comment: Try `fn$sqldf("select * from retrieve_data($name)")` as per example 5 on the sqldf home page: https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_5._Insert_Variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use `shQuote` and `sprintf` but there are clever way to do that I'm sure.

```
library(sqldf)
library(RPostgreSQL)

options(sqldf.RPostgreSQL.user = "****",
        sqldf.RPostgreSQL.dbname = "****",
        sqldf.RPostgreSQL.host = "localhost",
        sqldf.RPostgreSQL.port = 5432)

myfunc <- function(name)
    sqldf(sprintf("select * from retrieve_data(%s)", shQuote(name)))

myfunc('Bill')
##   id name year_born nationality
## 1 A1 Bill      2001    American
## 2 A2 Bill      1991    American
## 3 A3 Bill      1995    American
```

If you want to avoid quoting the string then you can use

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "tempdb")
myfunc2 <- function(name)
    dbGetQuery(con, "select * from retrieve_data($1)", name)

myfunc2("Bill")
##   id name year_born nationality
## 1 A1 Bill      2001    American
## 2 A2 Bill      1991    American
## 3 A3 Bill      1995    American
```

Comment: I think you would want `postgresqlEscapeStrings` instead of `shQuote` because you need quoting specific to SQL (and postgresql), not to a command line shell. (Though I'm not sure what you use for the `con` argument in this case.)

Comment: @BrianDiggs That's the main problem, I don't know how to find a `con` type object  using `sqlf`. I edited and proposed a cleaner approach